# Sort array from for statement

Tags: php, sorting

I have the following `PHP` statement and I want to sort the results.

```
for ($i=0; $i<$entries_Marketing["count"]; $i++){
    echo $entries_Marketing[$i]["cn"][0]." (".$entries_Marketing[$i]["mail"][0]."),<br />";
    $mail->addBCC ($entries_Marketing[$i]["mail"][0], $entries_Marketing[$i]["cn"][0]);
    $mail->clearAddresses(); 
}
```

Using `sort($entries_Marketing[$i]["cn"][0])` doesn't seem to work.
Any thoughts?

Comment: `for ($i=0; $i<$entries_Marketing["count"]; $i++){
 echo $entries_Marketing[$i]["cn"][0]." (".$entries_Marketing[$i]["mail"][0]."),<br />";
        $mail->addBCC ($entries_Marketing[$i]["mail"][0], $entries_Marketing[$i]["cn"][0]);
 $mail->clearAddresses(); 
}`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What does that variable contain, what are you expecting to happen, what does happen?

Comment: `$entries_Marketing` is produced from an AD search.
    `$result_Marketing = ldap_search($ad, $dn_Marketing, $filter, $attributes);`
    `$entries_Marketing = ldap_get_entries($ad, $result_Marketing);`